# How to pass list of s3 arns inside the terraform data resource aws_iam_policy_document

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass  multiple values to pricipals's identifiers in the data resource "aws_iam_policy_document".  getting the following error

Inappropriate value for attribute "identifiers": element 0: string required.

s3_values variable is defined type = any  and set the values as
....

> s3_values:

> ```
>   bucket: bucketname1
>   s3_arns:
>     - arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root
>     - arn:aws:iam::2345678901:role/s3-read-role
> ```

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {

count    = length(var.s3_arns)

```
     statement {
      sid    = "1"
      effect = "Allow"
      principals  {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = ["${var.s3_values[count.index]["s3_arns"]}"]
                  }  
      actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
      resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_values[count.index]["bucket"]}/*"]
     }
 
}
```

I get  the following error

Inappropriate value for attribute "identifiers": element 0: string required.

its working , when only one value is passed , but not working when we pass multiple values to the variable s3_arns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create multiple policy documents for a single S3 bucket. Rather than using count to create many documents, it would be best if you created a single policy document that gives access to each ARN you pass.

Currently it works for one ARN because the `identifiers` field gets passed a single string and creates a list with one string element. When you pass a list of ARNs, the `identifiers` field is instead creating a list with a list element that contains the ARN strings.

I would fix this by making the `s3_arns` field always be a list of strings, and removing the `count` field on the data resource. Once you do that you can change the line identifiers to be `identifiers = var.s3_values.s3_arns` and the resources line to be `resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_values.bucket}/*"]`

Comment: Thanks for your support. Actually, s3_values have multiple buckets and each bucket have different arns. So I need to use  `count` .  The actual s3_values variable is like this                                                                                           ```s3_values:
    -  bucket: bucketname1
     -  s3_arns:
          - arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root
          - arn:aws:iam::2345678901:role/s3-read-role```

Comment: ```s3_values:   ```  
           ```-  bucket: bucketname1  ```   
            ```-  s3_arns: ```  
                  ```- arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root```  
                    ```- arn:aws:iam::2345678901:role/s3-read-role```                                                                               
   ```-  bucket: bucketname2```    
   ```-  s3_arns```   
           ```- arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root```    
         ```- arn:aws:iam::2345678901:role/s3-read-role```

Comment: In that case it's best for your count to be based on the number of buckets instead of the number of `s3_arns`. Making sure that the `s3_arns` is always a list -- even if it only has one element -- would handle the original issue with `identifiers`.

When `s3_arns` is a list, then you can change the identifiers line to this:
`identifiers = var.s3_values[count.index]["s3_arns"]`